# Safe Subscripting of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-literals

With literals syntax one can use NSDictionary *dictionary like this to get the objectForKey

```
NSDictionary * dictionary;
id object = dictionary[key];
```

But if the type of dictionary is of type id and you try to write

```
id dictionary;
id object = dictionary[key];
```

This will work until if your dictionary was really a dictionary otherwise it would crash.

The solution for that would be to have a method

```
-(id)safeObject:(id)object forKey:(id)aKey {
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [object objectForKeyedSubscript:aKey];
}
```

So now when I call it like this

```
id dictionary;
id object = [self safeObject:dictionary forKey:key];
```

This won't crash. But the problem with this one is that If I have to go deeper in the nested dictionary for example

```
id object = dictionary[key1][subKey1][subsubKey1];
```

It is really convenient to write with the literal syntax with old syntax it would be something like

```
id mainObject = [self safeObject:dictionary forKey:key1];
id subObject = [self safeObject:mainObject forKey:subKey1];
id object = [self safeObject:subObject forKey:subsubKey1];
```

So not that much readable. I want to have this solution with new literal syntax is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `valueForKeyPath`, e.g.

```
id dictionary = @{@"key":@{@"subkey" : @{ @"subsubkey" : @"value"}}};
id object = [self safeObject:dictionary];
id value = [object valueForKeyPath:@"key.subkey.subsubkey"];
```

Also slightly change safeObject only to check if it's a dictionary,

```
- (id)safeObject:(id)object {
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return object;
}
```

Hope this helps, is this what you're looking for?